# Is it possible to have all your data in Sanity.io be stored locally instead of on the Content Lake

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

So I have a "simple" e-commerce next.js app that uses Sanity to manage the data. What I also have is an empty Alibaba server that I want to use to keep the data that is used in the app. My goal is to keep the data like images, ID, name, description, etc., on the Alibaba server, and connect said server to Sanity so that I can use the sanity studio UI to manage the data, and host the app. Is that possible? I've been looking around on the sanity docs for a while and I saw no mention of this, and nothing comes up on Google.

When I was starting to use Sanity, I did it on the server, expecting it to make a database somewhat like phpmyadmin does on the local server. It wasn't long until I realized that data didn't exist on my server and was with Sanity. I then went to the sanity website to see if there's an option or command for me to click/run and get it stored locally, but I saw nothing much (or maybe I'm just blind, iunno).